# [ecilpse][ The JavaScript editor is not installed

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin

The JavaScript editor has been removed during the installation process from the market.

the way i did it Generic Text Editor -> Default

BUT Editor Selection doesn't exist...

Is there no other way?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Install [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) for JavaScript language support in the Generic Text Editor.

Comment: What are you actually asking?